# How to get value from the table?

Tags: java, selenium, htmlelements

```
<table id="usersForm:mainTable:n" class="extdt-table-layout res-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%;" style="">
   <colgroup id="usersForm:mainTable:colgroup:body">
      <tbody id="usersForm:mainTable:tb">
         <tr id="usersForm:mainTable:n:0" class="extdt-firstrow rich-extdt-firstrow extdt-row-selected rich-sdt-row-selected res-table-selected" onmousedown="handleMouseClick(event)">
            <td id="usersForm:mainTable:1:name" class="extdt-cell rich-extdt-cell">
               <div class="extdt-cell-div">
                  <div onmouseup="if (showMenu(this)) {document.lkjasdf = event; selectContextMenu('ENTTUSER','MbUsersSearch');}">
                     <span title="ADMIN" onmouseup="if(!rightButton && isSelectedRow(this,rightButton) && false && !disableContext) {setDisableContext(true); beforePrepareDefaultAction('ENTTUSER','MbUsersSearch');}">ADMIN</span>
```

Using htmlelements pattern, i want get value from table, ie verify that table contains value "ADMIN".
In htmlelements can able work with tables "from the box". I wrote:

```
import ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.element.Table;
public class MainTableForm extends HtmlElement {
    @FindBy(id = "usersForm:mainTable:n")
    private Table table;
}
```

Then I do not know which method helps to get the value.

Comment: I am not sure about htmlelements, but you can check it without it i believe. Does this help - `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#usersForm:mainTable:n span[title="ADMIN"]")).getText()`. This should return you the `Admin` text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you post HTML please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to properly format it. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Same goes for your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List<List<String>> getRowsAsString()` method to get all the values from your table. Then just check this collection with hamcrest matcher. So the final code will be pretty simple:

```
assertThat(table.getRowsAsString(), contains(contains(equalTo("ADMIN"))));
```

Comment: IDE proposes to alter the code in assertThat (usersPage.tableValue (), (Matcher <? super List <List <String >>>) hasItem (hasItem (equalTo ("ADMIN")))); I get error: Error:(36, 97) java: incompatible types: org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? super java.lang.Iterable<? super java.lang.String>>> cannot be converted to org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.String>>>

Comment: try `contains` matcher instead of `hasItem`, i always messing up with them :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
WebElement adminSpan = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#usersForm:mainTable:n span[title='ADMIN']"));
System.out.println(adminSpan.getText().trim());
```

I added the `TABLE` id just in case there is more than one of these admin `SPAN`s. The CSS selector reads as find an element with an id (#) of `usersForm:mainTable:n` that has a descendant () `SPAN` with the `title` of ADMIN.

You may or may not need to `trim()`. I've gotten to the point where I just always `trim()` because it's easy and it saves me time finding and adding it later when I find out I needed it but didn't realize it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out by installing firepath
find out the path by firepath